# How to determine which is the exact address that operator new tries to allocate when it throws exception?

Tags: c++

```
Thread [1] (STOPPED) (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)  
    _block_mem_malloc_align() at 0xb8206f4f 
    _band_get_aligned() at 0xb820709f   
    _band_get() at 0xb82071e6   
    __malloc_lock() at 0xb820fa15   
    __malloc() at 0xb820fb28    
    _malloc() at 0xb8205d0b 
    malloc_allocator() at 0xb821975d    
    debug_allocator() at 0xb8219148 
    __debug_malloc() at 0xb8219799  
    mtrace_malloc() at 0xb821b9df   
    debug_malloc_l() at 0xb82196a6  
    operator new() at 0xb8208c66
```

During call to the new operator, it causes SIGSEGV, however, it the stack trace I'm unable to pinpoint which address new tries to give when it raises exception.

In the code snippet below:

```
int main(){
    CheckedPtr<int> aa = new int[4];

    aa[0] = 2;
    aa[1] = 2;
    aa[2] = 2;
    aa[3] = 2;
    aa[4] = 2;
    aa[5] = 1; //0x8084604 overflow

    CheckedPtr<CustomObject> bb = new CustomObject; //0x8088084
}
```

During call to the constructor, it overwrites the region 0x8084604 with some values and it did not crash. But somewhere inside the [CustomObject] where [new] is called it crashes. However, I can not pinpoint that [0x8084604] is causing the crash itself. Im hoping my question is clear.

Comment: Unless you're debugging the implementation of the memory manager, that's not an interesting piece of information You have most likely corrupted the memory manager's internal data at some earlier point in the program.

Comment: I understand your point. I'm just thinking if there is any way to find the exact relation of [0x8084604] and the [new]. What I mean an easy way. I'm using the [rcheck\malloc.h] to perform debugging using [mallopt()], however it does not pinpoint the issue. I wonder if these these tools are helpful.

Comment: It looks like you're delberately writing outside a dynamically allocated block of memory, which has undefined behaviour and is most likely what's corrupting the memory manager's bookkeeping. Once you've done that, all bets are off.

Comment: The is exactly what is happening to the actual program that has been running for a decade. Unfortunately, that program did not crash at all. We only find the issue when we start decoupling and modularising the parts and this issue happens. It's very tricky and difficult to debug. I keep thinking it's my module causing the error but it happened way before that call. Since we are integrating a lot of libraries with no debug information, it makes things difficult :(

Comment: The only tool I\m aware of that finds this kind of issue is clang's [Address Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html).

Comment: does this work in QNX? or are you aware?